# PHP preg_replace match numbers following a special character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm creating a comment board feature that allows users to reference post-ID's, which will be auto-configured by regex to hyperlink to the relevant post.

Posts references are formatted as the following, using the double-arrow ASCII symbol: `»1234`

6 numbers maximum can follow the double-arrow in order for the reference to be hyperlinked, so `»1234567` would not hyperlink, but `»1`, `»12`, `»123`, etc would.

How would I go about doing this with regex?

Comment: Maybe `^»\d{1,6}$`? Is `»1234567` the only input in the string?

Comment: No, there may be other text in the string too, but if it's joined to the reference then the hyperlinking should fail

Comment: What do you mean by `joined to the reference`? The `»123` will always have a trailing space or be the end of string?

Comment: If the reference is concatenated with any other string outside of the format it should break the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the special character followed by 1-6 digits and then followed by a word boundary, so it won't match if it's concatenated with any other string.

```
»\d{1,6}\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution: `»` matches the arrow character, `\d` matches a number between 0 and 9 and `{1,6}` specifies, that at least 1 and maximal 6 numbers should follow. If you want to match only whole words, you can use a word boundary on front and on back of the regex (`\b`). If you want to check if the whole string consists only of this pattern, you can use an anchor (`^` in the beginning, `$` at the end).

```
»\d{1,6}
```

Comment: Without an anchor, or `\D`, `»1234567` will also match.

Comment: Just append `(?!\d)` at the end